# ui:repeat renders (nearly!) nothing

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I have a `List` of **two** Objects and I am clueless what is going wrong

1. prints the String representations as it should
2. produces html output `<div> - </div>` - that is what I am struggling with
3. works fine too (shows both objects to select from - I do not intend to select - just a test)

I have the following facelets code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="myTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

        <!-- 1. -->
        you're managing: #{adminBean.managedPersons}

        <!-- 2. -->
        <div>
        <ui:repeat var="#{adminBean.managedPersons}" value="person">
        - #{person}
        </ui:repeat>
        </div>

        <!-- 3. -->
        <p:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItems value="#{adminBean.managedPersons}" var="person" itemLabel="#{person.name}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: So, having that three points done, what is your code exactly failing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mixed up `var`- and `value`-attributes on the `<ui:repeat>`.

WRONG:
`<ui:repeat var="#{adminBean.managedPersons}" value="person">`

RIGHT:
`<ui:repeat var="person" value="#{adminBean.managedPersons}">`

It's was not the first time, this drives me nuts. Maybe this will help someone...

Comment: That should be a comment, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, as it is the answer/resolution to my question, isn't it? Otherwise this would stay an "unanswered" question, although it's resolved? Do you object?

Comment: @XtremeBiker You have to wait 2 days to accept your own answer.